# Keep single storyboard for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

I am creating a demo project for keeping single storyboard for both iPad and iPhone devices. I am going to use Xcode 8 first time.

I created a button and put this button in center of the View with using constraints. I successfully managed the width and height of the button according to the device. On iPhone width is 100 and height is 50. And on iPad width is 200 and height is 100. To achieve this I used "Vary for Traits".

So I just want to know, am I on correct flow, I mean, to achieve size classes "Vary for Traits" is the correct ways OR is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes you are. Good luck.

Comment: @Poles.... Thanks .....

Comment: Yes thats spot on. Any variations that you need for iPad use vary for traits as you are

Comment: @AlexMcPherson ... Okay I keep this thing in my mind.... Thanks.... :)'

Comment: @SarabjitSingh no problem :-)

Comment: I done with iPhone and iPad.... but I'm totally confused with, how I make button different sizes on iPhone devices....Please help me regarding this....