# Different iPhone devices with single storyboard by using Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

With reference to my previously asked question,

> [Keep single storyboard for iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934204/keep-single-storyboard-for-iphone-and-ipad)

I done with above issue. I successfully created the iPhone and iPad design with single storyboard by using

> Vary of traits

But now my issue is , I want to make button's different width and height and all related constraints according to the different iPhone screen sizes.
If I am using "Vary of traits" it will update button for all screen sizes for iPhone.

For eg:

> 1. iPhone 6: I want to set button top constraint from superview is 100
> 2. iPhone 5s: I want to set button top constraint from superview is 60

Please suggest me regarding this.

Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: use adaptivelayout

Comment: iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s  both are in the same category means wC- hR [Portrait], wC- hC[landscape]. So reflects both sides.Go with by code.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by storyboard.....

Comment: use autolayout and change the topContraint.constant value based on device type. have to do it programatically

Comment: i tried but its not updating the constants.....

Answer (score 0):

```
topConstraint.constant = xx
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```